# pasar datos con ajax a otra pagina desde datatable

Tags: ajax, datatables

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente inconveniente tengo una datatable con datos extraidos desde mysql, le agrego un boton editar para poder enviar los datos de esa fila a otra pagina php no se como hacerlo. En las columnas agrego DefaultContent y coloco el boton pero nesesito enviar a la pagina encuestasave.php el id adjunto el codigo del script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    listar();
});

var listar = function(){
    var table =  $("#contribu").DataTable({
        "destroy":true,
        "ajax":{
            "method":"POST",
            "url":"listar.php"
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data":"id_encuestado"},
            {"data":"reclamo"},
            {"data":"tipo"},
            {"data":"Fecha_Alta"},
            {"data":"Direccion"},
            {"data":"Nombre"},
            {"data":"Apellido"},
            {"data":"Dni"},
            {"data":"Telefono"},
            {"defaultContent":"<button type='button' class='edit'</button> "}
        ],

    });

}
```

Los datos los traigo de la pagina listar.php y cargo el datatable. Una vez cargado necesito que el boton edit de DefaultContent lo envie a la pagina encustasave.php para llenar otros campos.Muchas Gracias

Comment: lo primero es cerrar bien la etiqueta del `button` `<button type='button' class='edit'></button>`

Comment: y la pagina `encustasave.php` espera un parametro, un `id` del registro seleccionado, verdad?

Comment: ok.perdon...no me di cuenta

Comment: si con extract($_GET); obtiene el id

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código.

Lo que hace este código básicamente es indicar que en el ultimo registro se escribirá de forma distinta que las demás columnas, pasando por una función la cual retorna el elemento requerido agregando en este caso el enlace a la pagina de edición con el id.

Ahí eres libre de agregar lo que estimes conveniente, si no es un botón un enlace, etc.

```
"columns":[
            {"data":"id_encuestado"},
            {"data":"reclamo"},
            {"data":"tipo"},
            {"data":"Fecha_Alta"},
            {"data":"Direccion"},
            {"data":"Nombre"},
            {"data":"Apellido"},
            {"data":"Dni"},
            {"data":"Telefono"},
            {   "data": null,
                render: function(data, type, row){
                    return "<button type='button' class='edit' onClick='window.location=encustasave.php?id="+data['id_encuestado']+"'></button>"
                },
                "targets": -1
            }
        ],
```

Comment: no funciona ...cambie el nombre de encuestasave.php que esta ba mal pero igual no hace nada...

Comment: Comprueba que el id este escribiendo bien `data['id_encuestado']` ponlo entre las etiquetas del `button` así: `<button>"+data['id_encuestado']+"</button>` o `<button>"+data[0]+"</button>`

Comment: No, es mas la funcion por si sola  es decir sin igualar a la variable  no me retorna a la pagina encuestasave.php

Comment: el boton te lleva a la pagina o no hace nada, que sale en la consola?

Comment: The message port closed before a response was received. me sale ese error

Comment: perdon al presionar el boton me da "Unexpected end of input" el error

Answer (score 0):

A mi me  funciono de esta manera:

{   "data": null,
render: function(data, type, row){
return "<a target='_blank' href='informe_ajuste.php?idreferencia="+data['id']+"'>"},

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/350405)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).